# I have Connect my Java Code to Oracle but its give me Error:

Tags: eclipse

```
package JDBC;

import java.sql.*;

public class Project {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try

        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@dbHost:1521:productDB”");
            Statement st=Con.createStatement();
            String sql  = "select * from emp";


            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next())

                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
            Con.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e)

        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: @RudyVissers Why don't you kindly mark as a duplicate if you can find said answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Network Adapter could not establish the connection in SQL developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524694/the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-in-sql-developer)

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC connection URL says `dbHost`. Is that correct ? Ideally it should be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` if you have installed it locally or some LAN IP like `192.168.1.2` or `10.10.10.10`.

Also it seems that you have an additional double quote at the end of it. `jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@dbHost:1521:productDB”`.

If you have a telnet client enabled try doing `telnet <host> 1521`.